# Лицензия GNU GPL и Windows

Tags: windows, gcc, лицензирование

Такой вопрос, может ли быть, что созданная программа на gcc компилятор 
 [wiki gcc](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection)  на операционной системе Windows, интерпретатор или компилятор, компания Microsoft потребует права на программу, мол на нашей ОС написали?

Comment: Маловероятно. Каким способом?

Comment: замените `...на нашей ос...` на `...для нашей ос...` и все встанет на свои места

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, такого быть не может. Это как если бы производитель кошельков заявил права на все ваши деньги.